# Calling a C++ DLL from Visual Basic

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I've been trying to read data from an Oculus Rift for a while. I want it to work in Visual basic, but the only code available worked in C++. So I made a C++ DLL that read data from the rift, and I want to use it in VB. The problem is I don't quite know what I'm doing with this, so If you could keep in mind that I'm a real noob, thad be great.

I used this tut on how to create the DLL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdSbp1A6eQc

Here is the C++ code to read the data off the rift:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "OVR_CAPI_D3D.h"
#include "Extras/OVR_Math.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace OVR;

int main()
{
 ovrHmd HMD;
 ovrGraphicsLuid luid;
 ovr_Initialize(nullptr);
 ovr_Create(&HMD, &luid);
 ovrHmdDesc hmdDesc = ovr_GetHmdDesc(HMD);

   float yaw, pitch, roll;

  while (true)
 {
  double frameTime = ovr_GetPredictedDisplayTime(HMD, 0);
  double sensorSampleTime = ovr_GetTimeInSeconds();
  ovrTrackingState hmdState = ovr_GetTrackingState(HMD, frameTime, ovrTrue);
  ovrPosef thePose = hmdState.HeadPose.ThePose;
  Quatf(thePose.Orientation).GetYawPitchRoll(&yaw, &pitch, &roll);

  cout << "yaw: " << RadToDegree(yaw) << ", pitch: " << RadToDegree(pitch) << ", roll: " << RadToDegree(roll) << endl;
}

ovr_Destroy(HMD);
ovr_Shutdown();
}
```

I made another C++ program and tested the DLL, and everthing checked out.
I then made a VB program to import the DLL, but I can't make it work:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System


Module Module1
Private Declare Sub getriftinfo Lib "RiftDLL.dll" Alias "getriftdata" ()

Sub Main()
    getriftinfo()
End Sub

End Module
```

When I run the code, the program crashes and a console message shows up saying:
 *unhandled exception system.badimageformatexception an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format*

Also, I wasn't quite sure where to put the DLL

Thanks guys! It means a lot.

Comment: Instead of declaring it via code, did you try just adding it as a reference in your project and adding it as an import so you can reference it?

Comment: Can you show me how? I'm all ears.

Comment: Does that work with C++ DLLs?

Comment: sorry, I just realized, you can only add a managed DLL as a reference, not a native C++ dll. Here's someone with a similar question, check out the first answer that explains how to setup the declaration: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4624961a-bbd7-4b19-811c-bda211d2d87c/c-dll-in-vbnet?forum=vbgeneral

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure both programs are targeting 32 bit or 64 bit.  If you are mixing 32 bit and 64 bit libraries it could throw this kind of error.

I suppose your right that the dll might be in the wrong location.  Generally, you can include it in your bin and then include the reference in your project in visual studio.

This answer might help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f228007d-35eb-4ab5-b541-c10ece3b980b/help-using-c-dll-functions-in-vbnet?forum=vblanguage.

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I compiled both on the same PC, how could they have different bit rates?

Comment: In visual studio project compile options you target x64, x86, or anyCPU.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that you are calling unmanaged code from managed code.  According to this post they seem to suggest that this is only possible for 32 bit code or x86.  http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/callunmanaged.html

Comment: All working! The problem was that one of the librarys I was using needed the DLL to be coded in 64 bit, while VB needed 86.